# How can insert order of an enter selection be controlled?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an enter selection with two elements that I want to prepend to a svg container such that the order of the two elements is maintained. I have tried using insert using the :first-child selector like this

```
var newlayers = layer.enter();
newlayers.insert("g",":first-child")
```

As a result of using the :first-child selector the second element in the enter selection ends up being the first element in the svg container after insertion. How can I avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I was able to reorder the elements using .sort after the insert selection is created in this way:

```
var newlayers = layer.enter();
newlayers.insert("g",":first-child")
.sort(function(a,b){ return b-a; });
```

This leaves the ordering of the data intact while only reordering the inserted elements in DOM. I went down the route of reordering the data returned on enter() itself and that opened a whole new bunch of other problems.